# Understanding ZooKeeper startup command line

Tags: java, jar, apache-zookeeper

I was reading the `ZooKeeper Cluster Set-Up Document` from [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup) .

But unfortunately can't understand the java command to start up ZooKeeper service.

`$ java -cp zookeeper.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:conf \ org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain zoo.cfg`

As far as I knew(Please correct if I was wrong.thanks), `-cp` means `-classpath` option. `:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar` means the reference libraries of the executable jar `zookeeper.jar`. `org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain` is the main class which command needed. and `zoo.cfg` means the argument of the main class.

What I can't understand is the `:conf \` part. What does it mean?

I tried to read the document from [Java document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html). But didn't anything helpful.

Could someone please help to shed some light on it ?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conf` part adds classes and resources from the `conf` directory to the classpath.

The classpath contains three entries:

- `zookeeper.jar`, i.e. the Zookeeper JAR file in the current working directory
- `lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar`, i.e. the Log4J JAR file in the `lib` directory
- `conf`, i.e. all compiled classes and resources in the `conf` directory

The backslash is just there to indicate to the shell that the command continues on the next line.

Comment: Why I didn't found it in the official document? Did I missed something ? Please show me the document link. many thanks.

Comment: What document link? It's just a standard Java classpath. The backslash is just to indicate to the shell that the command continues on the next line.

Comment: You mean the conf is also the reference library path just like the part `:lib/log4j..`?

Comment: The classpath can contain directories as well as libraries (JAR) files. I'll elaborate a little more in my answer.

Comment: Forgive me bad understanding. So the `conf` is just a directory name. not an option kind of thing from `java` command ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's it indeed.

Comment: Thanks your nice help. Now I am totally understanding ! ++++1